# How to add AWS SDK to OSGi environment

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, osgi

How can I use the AWS Java SDK in my OSGi bundle? I've added the following dependecy in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.27</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I install it in Apache Felix enviroment I get the following error for missing packages:

```
missing package(s) or can not resolve all of the them: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.model, com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb, com.amazonaws.auth
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an OSGi bundle that exports that package to be able to access it at runtime.

If there is not an OSGi bundle for the aws-java-sdk you can create your own by creating a bundle that includes and exports that package.

See this question here: [Non-osgi library usage in an osgi application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931292/non-osgi-library-usage-in-an-osgi-application)

Note it is also possible to embed the library directly in your OSGi bundle, however Id reccommend against this in order to keep your application more  modular.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've tried to embed the libraries but it doesn't work. It doesn't activate the bundle properly.

Comment: Ok, I would obviously need more info to be able to help. What error do you see in the felix console

Comment: When I add <Embed-Dependency>, <Embed-Transitive> and add <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package> there aren't any errors, but the activate method doesn't run properly. How can I disable all imported package?

Comment: Try it without resolution:=optional it might give you an error then in the felix console. If not check logs for any errors.

Comment: Please provide a worked example demonstrating how to do this.