# OSGi bundle imports packages from non-bundle jars: create bundles for them?

Tags: java, jar, osgi

I am new to OSGi, and am using Equinox.  I have done several searches and can find no answer to this.  The discussion at [OSGI - handling 3rd party JARs required by a bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340483/osgi-handling-3rd-party-jars-required-by-a-bundle) helps somewhat, but does not fully answer my question.

I have obtained a jar file, `rabbitmq-client.jar`, that is already packaged as an OSGi bundle (with Bundle-Name and other such properties in its MANIFEST.MF), that I would like to install as a bundle.  This jar imports packages `org.apache.commons.io` and `org.apache.commons.io.input` from `commons-io-1.2.jar`.  The RabbitMQ client 2.7.1 distribution also includes `commons-cli-1.1.jar`, so I presume that it is required as well.

I examined the manifests of these commons jars and found that they do not appear to be packaged as bundles.  That is, their manifests have none of the standard bundle properties.

My specific question is: if I install `rabbitmq-client.jar` as a bundle, what is the proper way to get access to the packages that it needs to import from the commons jars?  There are only three alternatives that I can think of, without rebuilding `rabbitmq-client.jar`.

1. The packages from the commons jars are already included in the Equinox global classpath, and `rabbitmq-client.jar` will get them automatically from there.
2. I must make another bundle with the two commons jars, export the needed packages, and install that bundle in Equinox.
3. I must put these two commons jars in the global classpath when I start Equinox, and they will be available to `rabbitmq-client.jar` from there.

I have read that one normally does not use the global classpath in an OSGi container.  I am not clear on whether items from the global classpath are even available when building individual bundle classpaths.  However, I note that `rabbitmq-client.jar` also imports other packages such as `javax.net`, which I presume come from the global classpath.  Or is there some other bundle that exports them?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 5):

Solution (2) is the correct way. (1) and (3) will not work because, as you seem to understand already, there is no such thing as a global classpath in OSGi.

Each bundle imports all the packages that it needs, and those packages must be exported by another bundle. There is an exception to this, which is all the classes under the `java.*` namespace... i.e. there is no need to import `java.lang`, `java.util` etc.

Packages such as `javax.net` do come from the JRE but they are still not on a "global classpath". There is a special bundle called the System Bundle, which represents the OSGi Framework itself within OSGi. That bundle exports a bunch of packages that come from the JRE such as `javax.net`, `javax.swing`, `org.w3c.dom`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @neil, that helps.  I have read a few OSGi tutorials, but none answered these questions exactly.  I guess I'll be stumbling around as an OSGi newbie for a while until I figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

I'd also add to what Neil has said that for popular bundles, like commons-io, there's usually no need for option (2), since someone else has already done it. There is a SpringSource repository with many converted bundles. For commons-io you can do even better, since version 1.4 of the 'official'  jar on maven central is already a bundle.

Comment: Thanks, @holly, that helps.  I did look at SpringSource and saw a bundle for commons-io but not for commons-cli.  I'll have to look at it again.

Comment: Just a comment: `rabbitmq-client.jar` shouldn't actually need either `commons-cli` or `commons-io` any more (since release 2.8.0).  These jars are supplied in the `rabbitmq` repository for running some tests.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to add non-OSGI jars to `Bundle-classpath` in `MANIFEST.MF`.

In the following example, a generic reference includes all jars inside folder "libs" (located in the bundle's root folder) and adds them to the bundle classpath.

Although in general it's considered not a good practice (versus explicitly importing required packages), to add all the packages automatically, `DynamicImport-Package` can be used. When the jars are put inside a separate "wrapper" bundle, as proposed bei Neil Bartlett, that shouldn't do much harm:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: libs/*.jar
DynamicImport-Package: *
```

In this case, for other, non-jar dependencies, e. g. dll files, adding the following to `build.properties` will include everything from folder "libs" and its subfolders into the bundle, with the same folder structure:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
           .,\
           libs/**
```