# Cannot start OSGi bundle, missing com.ibm.uvm.tools

Tags: java, maven, osgi, maven-bundle-plugin, osgi-bundle

I am trying to start a bundle, with a whole bunch of dependencies. I am getting the error `could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: com.ibm.uvm.tools`, but  cannot find this package in the maven repos or on the web. By marking this package (and a bunch of others) optional in the Import-Package directive, I can resolve the package, but it fails to start if the dependencies are not met. What can I do to resolve this Import-package?

I am using the maven-bundle-plugin to generate the bundle.

Comment: What bundle are you trying to install? What error do you get when you make the package optional? When I google "uvm tool" google actually suggests the package you are looking for, so I really wonder how you could not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was to use a OSGified version of log4j as provided dependency. I had it as a compiled dependency. Log4j manifest mentions this package as an optional depndency, so maven-bundle-plugin added it to my bundle's manifest, but did not make it optional.

Answer (score 2):

You have built your bundle with a couple of jars on the classpath. Otherwise your bundle would not reference anything in a package named `com.ibm.uvm.tools`. Now you need to see whether or not this jar is OSGi-ready (specifying the correct headers and package-exports). Maybe there also exists a 'OSGi-fied' version of that jar, have look at [the springsource repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/) for example.

Looking at the package name, I assume the probably proprietary code that cannot be found re-wrapped in any public repository, then you may try to wrap it as a bundle yourself , having a look [at this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340483/osgi-handling-3rd-party-jars-required-by-a-bundle).