# Knopflerfish, use external library in bundle

Tags: java, osgi, knopflerfish

I know there are two ways of using external libraries in OSGI bundles. As only my package needs the lib (e.g. google-gson) I tried to put it in the `Bundle-ClassPath` (manifest.mf). But whenever I run the bundle in Knopflerfish I get the `Exception in thread "Thread-74" [stderr] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson`.

As I am new to OSGI I tried to follow the instructions for creating a bundle from [here](http://www.knopflerfish.org/releases/current/docs/tutorials/kf_osgi_tutorial/kf_osgi_tutorial.pdf) using a `build.xml` for compilation where I also included the lib (don't know if this is even correct). So the library appears in three different places, the *project classpath*, the *bundle classpath* (manifest.mf) and the *build.xml*.

I would be glad if someone could give me a hint how to make the library work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the end I choose the second approach and created an OSGI bundle from google-gson. So I do not need to care about including the library into my bundle. Everything else was not working :(

Answer (score 1):

The process as follows

1.copy all the `.jar` files and its DEPENDENCIES to a folder

2.mention it in `BUNDLE-CLASSPATH` in `MANIFEST.MF` .Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340483/osgi-handling-3rd-party-jars-required-by-a-bundle/1340565#1340565)

3.Importantly add *packages* from this library to `Export-package` element in `MANIFEST.MF` to make it visible for other bundles.

Hope this resolves your issue

Answer (score 0):

Few hints that may help and work for me:

- The MANIFEST.MF of the bundle may have a line like `Import-Package: org.osgi.framework`. In that line you should add the import of the desired package from the library, so it remains `Import-Package: org.osgi.framework, com.google.gson`
- As TheWhiteRabbit said in its answer, libraries should have an export line like `Export-Package: its.sec.api.service`, so other bundles may see it. Libraries that are already compiled and packaged usually are already setup, but I found some that hasn't so is a good practice to check it.

Also remember that external libraries may be installed into the framework as if it were bundles, i.e. in the init.xargs `- install jars/myLib/myLibrary.jar` **Installed but not started**.

Hope this helps